# Pytest - how to structure the tests efficiently

Tags: python, pytest

Suppose there are 2 endpoints to be tested.

Endpoint 1 returns data that needs to be used in a request to endpoint 2.

How to get 2 endpoints tested efficiently?

```py
# file_1.py

def test_endpoint_1():
    r = requests.get(...)

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation

    return r
```

```py
# file_2.py

from file_1 import test_endpoint_1

def test_endpoint_2():
    needed_data = test_endpoint_1()
    r = requests.get(..., payload=needed_data.json())

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation
```

Above approach kinda works but if I execute the test suite we are testing endpoint_1 twice. I could change the name of test_endpoint_1() to avoid that but maybe there is an easier and more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hard coded value

Generally, we "assume" that dependencies are working correctly.
In this case, keep it simple and create an hardcoded value in the test.

```py
# file_2.py

def test_endpoint_2():
    needed_data = "JSON"  # valid return example from test_endpoint_1
    r = requests.get(..., payload=needed_data)

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation
```

## pytest.fixture

If you need this value in many tests, create a fixture instead. This will allows you to edit the "valid value" for endpoint_2 in one place instead of changing it in every tests that depend on it.

I advise you to put your fixtures in a `conftest.py` file. This is explained [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files).

```py
# conftest.py

import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def endpoint_1_value_200():
    return "JSON"

# file_2.py

def test_endpoint_2(endpoint_1_value_200):
    r = requests.get(..., payload=endpoint_1_value_200)

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing endpoint1 is just *one* way to get a suitable payload for endpoint2. Another is to just provide a hard-coded payload.

```
# file_2.py


def test_endpoint_2():
    needed_data = {"foo": "bar"}  # Whatever is appropriate

    r = requests.get(..., payload=needed_data.json())

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a separate function :

```
def check_endpoint_1():
    r = requests.get(...)

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation

    return r

def test_endpoint_1():
    check_endpoint_1()

def test_endpoint_2():
    needed_data = check_endpoint_1()
    r = requests.get(..., payload=needed_data.json())

    assert r.status_code == 200
    maybe some JSON Schema validation
```